# Hot to send ajax request with cljs-ajax with its body keys without colons

Tags: javascript, ajax, dictionary, clojure, clojurescript

I'm using cljs-ajax and trying to send POST request with something like:

```
(POST "http://example.com/some/endpoint"
      {:body {:username "me"
              :password "pass"}
      :handler some-handler
      :error-handler some-error-handler})
```

This sends request but request payloads contains colons before keywords. Like, I'm expecting `username` to be sent but instead `:username`. I've tried to add `:format :json` but it changes nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used cljs-ajax before but from reading the documentation should you be using :params rather than :body, cljs-ajax should recognise this as a POST request and send the information in the body, if it was a GET request it would add it as a query string.

> :params - the parameters that will be sent with the request, format
>   dependent: :transit and :edn can send anything, :json, :text and :raw
>   need to be given a map. GET will add params onto the query string,
>   POST will put the params in the body

Don't forget to add those JSON format flags if it doesn't work the first time.

Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Hah it works! I've tried a lot of combinations from the docs but didn't try this most obvious one. Thanks!